# Count the maximum number of rows in another google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to count the maximum number of rows in other google sheets. Actually, Each spreadsheet has a number of tabs and I want the maximum row number of all tabs under each spreadsheet.

I find that `IMPORTRANGE` function can get the data from other spreadsheet with URL, however, this function can only read the data with sheet name. To get the sheet name list, I think the function below might be useful:

```
function sheetnames() { 
var out = new Array()
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
return out
}
```

But this function only works in the sheet it is in and to write this function in every single sheet is obviously impossible, so here is my question:

**Is it possible to  improve the `sheetnames()`function to get the sheet names from other sheets? (with URL? I'm not sure) Or How can I realize it with other methods?**

Thanks a lot for your patience!

Answer (score 2):

### For a Single Sheet:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  return SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(`SPREADSHEET_URL`)
                       .getSheets()
                       .map(i => [i.getSheetName(), i.getLastRow()])
                       // To view results:
                       //.forEach(i => Logger.log(i))

}
```

Output:

```
[
  [Sheet1, 10],
  [Sheet2, 15],
  [Sheet3, 20]
]
```

### For Multiple Sheets:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  const spreadsheetUrlList = [
    `...`,
    `...`,
    `...`
  ]

  return spreadsheetUrlList.map(i => {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(i)
    return {
      SpreadsheetName: spreadsheet.getName(),
      Sheets: [
        ...spreadsheet.getSheets()
                      .map(i => [i.getSheetName(), i.getLastRow()])
      ]
    }
  })
  // To view results:
  //.forEach(i => i.Sheets.forEach(item => Logger.log(`(${i.SpreadsheetName}) "${item[0]}": ${item[1]}`)))

}
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    SpreadsheetName: `MySpreadsheet`,
    Sheets: [
      ['Sheet1', 50],
      ['Sheet2', 40]
    ]
  },
  {
    SpreadsheetName: `MySpreadsheet2`,
    Sheets: [
      ['Sheet1', 30],
      ['Sheet2', 70]
    ]
  },
...
]
```

Let me know if you have any questions or would like different output formats!

Comment: Sorry! Updated with `.openByUrl()`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the url of a spreadsheet, this function will return the maximum number of rows of all sheets of the said spreadsheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL GOES HERE");
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

  let currentMaximum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var numberOfRows = sheets[i].getMaxRows();
    
    if (numberOfRows > currentMaximum){
      currentMaximum = numberOfRows;
    }
  }

  return currentMaximum;
}
```

It makes use of the [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) function to fetch an array containing all the sheets of the spreadsheet, it then loops through all those sheets, uses the [getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows) function to get the number of rows in each spreadsheet and finally updates the `currentMaximum` variable if a new maximum of rows is found.

Answer (score 0):

#### Max rows for spreadsheet

```
function maxrows(id=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()) {
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets().map(sh => sh.getMaxRows()).sort((a,b) => b - a)[0]);
}

Execution log
12:03:34 PM Notice  Execution started
12:03:34 PM Info    4994.0
12:03:35 PM Notice  Execution completed
```